# Android and PhoneGap

Tags: android

I had an urge to learn android to build apps and games, as it looked like a fun language especially if you had prior knowledge to some Java. I also found out that there are other frameworks that convert their codes into native features to apps like PhoneGap and then there is Unity that helps in cross-platform game development which uses javascript, c# and boo. My question is if frameworks like these exist why do we need to learn the native languages? What difference does it make?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Using Native Languages

Advantages

> The native applications allow the full use of the device capabilities
>   which might be missing in other third party APIs.
>  It is easier to get
>   good performance for the application when programming using native
>   SDKs.

Disadvantages

> Requires learning different languages for development on different
>   platforms. 
> The code base developed for one platform cannot be easily
>   adapted for another platform.

### Using Frameworks like PhoneGap

Developers can build applications using HTML/CSS/JS, including JavaScript classes that give access to device hardware and other iOS API featurs like contacts, filesystem, camera, microphone, GPS, etc. The final application is wrapped within a platform native 'Web View' browser object, and essentially becomes a stand-alone web application with the ability to access some device- specific features.

Advantages

> One can use plain old Javascript or even other libraries like jQuery,
>   Prototype, Sencha Touch, MooTools, etc to handle the interaction.
>   
> Allows the development for several platforms at once, e.g. Android,
>   iOS, Windows etc.

Disadvantages

> The applications are web applications inside a Web-View. Browser
>   performance doesn't come close to native application component
>   performance.
>  Not all device APIs would be available for the
>   applications.

Answer (score 0):

Most of these frameworks are aimed to overcome one or more hurdles such as; rapid development, memory reference counting; not having to learn a new language as well as a new platform; maintainability and many more.

Most of these frameworks are excellent until you start to have; larger apps, need very fast graphics, lots of memory, access to device hardware.

In reality all computer languages are frameworks /  translation between human expression and simple "decrement jump not zero" of the CPU/GPU inner core.

Therefore it depends on what you want to do and how much time you have.

I like to have a lot of help; good libraries of tested code, a lot of other developers using the same so that I can check stack overflow for help and of course a never ending challenge of learning new stuff, I choose my development environment to meet these goals and do a lot of research to find the bad points of each option.

eg. Swift looks interesting but it's new so I will wait for others to find its issues first, publish some performance benchmarks and see if there will be an open source port of it, like there was for .net.